# Differentiability and continuity at the origin of piecewise defined $g(x,y) = y-x^2$, $y+x^2$, or $0$

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, functions

> $$g(x,y)=
> \begin{cases}
> y-x^2,  & y\ge x^2\\
> y+x^2, & y\le -x^2\\
> 0 & \text-x^2\le y\le x^2
> \end{cases}$$

I need to find all the directional derivatives at the origin in the tangent space and show whether the function is differentiable in the origin

My work:

If $x=y$ approaches zero from positive values, then $$g(x,x)=\lim_{x\to0} \frac{x-x^2}{x}=1$$ and if $x=-y$ approaches zero from negative values, then

$$g(x,x)=\lim_{x\to0} \frac{x+x^2}{x}=1$$

So the function is continuous at the origin. How can I show that the function is differentiable and find all the directional derivatives at the origin in the tangent space?

Can you please give a methodological answer so that I can get a feeling for solving this kind of problems in general? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why are you dividing by $x$ to show $g$ is continuous at the origin?

Comment: @zhw. because x is approaching $0$. By definition, I should divide by $0$

Comment: I think you're confusing continuity with directional derivatives (or something). See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as continuity: Since $x^2$ and $y$ are in additive relationship, independently of the path, if both tend to $0$ the limit is zero. So the function is continuous at $(0,0)$. **I don't understand why you divided by $x$, though...**

Considering the [definition of the directional derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directional_derivative) we need a vector of absolute value one:
$$\overline v=\begin{bmatrix}\cos(\alpha)\\\sin(\alpha)\end{bmatrix}$$
then the limit below is the directional derivative in the direction of $\overline v$:
$$\nabla_{\overline v}g(x,y)=\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{g(x+h\cos(\alpha),y+\sin(\alpha))-g(x,y)}{h}.$$

So,

$$\nabla_{\overline v}g(x,y)= \lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\begin{cases}
\frac{y+h\sin(\alpha)-(x+h\cos(\alpha))^2-y+x^2}{h}&\text{ if }& \ \ \ \ y\ge x^2\\
\frac{y+h\sin(\alpha)+(x+h\cos(\alpha))^2-y-x^2}{h}&\text{ if }&\ \ \ \ y\le -x^2\\
0&\text{ if }& -x^2<y<x^2
\end{cases}=$$

$$= \lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\begin{cases}
\frac{h\sin(\alpha)-2xh\cos(\alpha))^2-h^2\cos^2(\alpha)}{h}&\text{ if }& \ \ \ \ y\ge x^2\\
\frac{h\sin(\alpha)+2hx\cos(\alpha)^2+h^2\cos^2(\alpha)}{h}&\text{ if }&\ \ \ \ y\le -x^2\\
0&\text{ if }& -x^2<y<x^2
\end{cases}=$$

$$= \lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\begin{cases}
\sin(\alpha)-2x\cos(\alpha)^2-h\cos^2(\alpha)&\text{ if }& \ \ \ \ y\ge x^2\\
\sin(\alpha)+2x\cos(\alpha)^2+h\cos^2(\alpha)&\text{ if }&\ \ \ \ y\le -x^2\\
0&\text{ if }& -x^2<y<x^2
\end{cases}=$$

$$= \begin{cases}
\sin(\alpha)-2x\cos^2(\alpha)&\text{ if }& \ \ \ \ y\ge x^2\\
\sin(\alpha)+2x\cos^2(\alpha)&\text{ if }&\ \ \ \ y\le -x^2\\
0&\text{ if }& -x^2<y<x^2
\end{cases}.$$

We are interested in the directional derivative at $(0,0)$ so

$$\nabla_{\overline v}g(0,0)=\sin(\alpha).$$

Comment: It is not sufficient to check lines through the origin for continuity.

Comment: @zhv: You are right. This is why I mentioned the additive relationship between $x$ and $y$. If both tend to $0$ then their sum tends to zero as well.

Comment: What is the $g(x,mx)$ all about then?

Comment: @zhw: You are right again. (I am simply used to trying the straight lines to see if there is discontinuity. There was no negative result so I stepped forward to the general argument...) I delete the unnecessary argumentation. Thank you for this comment.

Answer (score 1):

$g(x,0)= 0 \implies g_x(0,0) = 0, g(0,y) = y \implies g_y(0,0) = 1.$ So if $Dg(0,0)$ exists, it must be the linear transformation $(x,y)\to y.$ The question is then: Is it true that $$g(x,y) = g(0,0) + y + o((x^2+y^2)^{1/2})$$ as $(x,y) \to (0,0)$? Yes! But I'll leave that one for you. (It will require some thought.)

Given the above, the directional derivatives are standard. If $u=(a,b)$ is a unit vector, then $D_uf(0,0) = (0,1)\cdot (a,b) = b.$